# How to pass date object to a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker plugin along with some text fields. I pass the field content data to the function using AJAX. I am obtaining `object object` when I alert the value of

```
var dateObject = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
```

How am I supposed to pass this object through my AJAX function? Is there some other way by which I could covert this data object?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test_play/score",
    data: 'data1='+data1+'&data2='+data2+'&data3='+data3,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
    }
```

Comment: `alert(object);` will show the literal interpretation of your variable. what you need is `console.log(object);` so that you can use the console and inspect the object. (to see the console, right click on your page, choose inspect element (or just press F12) and see the console tab - Google Chrome)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Convert the data back to where. Call the function?

Comment: can i convert this data object into a non-object form,so that i can pass it to the custom function via ajax..

Comment: your date object probably have a `value` property that can be accessed by `dateObject.value` for instance. You'd have to log it to see what it contains, or, you can as well read the datepicker documentation.

Comment: tanx for the reply,but i get a "undefined" alert when i try to print dateObject.value

Comment: tanx for the help @Twisted1919. Finally got it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

as for edge version of jQueryUI, it must be string
as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kitteh/JPhww/)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker()
$('#button').click(function(){
  var dateObject = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate')
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/html/",
    data: {html: dateObject},
    success: function(data){
        $('#echo').html(data)
    }
  })
})
```